# What happened to the comments on a question?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375209/dirac-once-said-that-renormalization-is-just-a-stop-gap-procedure-and-there-had) question on renormalisation in quantum field theory had a number of comments under the main question, including one of mine; they *all* seemed to have been removed without any indication that they had been so. How come?

Comment: Comments, such as this one, are not expected to stay around. Other meta questions, and mother meta, reveal the mechanisms for that, including robots and miderators.

Comment: @JonCuster Wait, robots? I know about the [dead-question robot](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), but I don't know about any similar process for *automatically* removing comments.

Comment: @rob - if I recall, one of the bots flags long comment chains for human action. That at least makes them culpable, and certainly can be blamed!

Comment: I guess this comment chains going to get flagged for human action ;).

Comment: @MoziburUllah-In the first comment, Jon Custer writes about mother meta. Is that a person or what. Or did he made a typing error, by unintentionally writing an "m" previous to "other", resulting in "mother"? I guess the last is the case.

Comment: @descheleschilder "mother meta" is a colloquial name for [meta.se].

Comment: Mother meta sounds good in the sense that it is a nice (?) alliteration, but nevertheless, I think I like **grandma meta** better!

Answer (score 1):

Comments are for criticizing or clarifying the question or for linking related questions, not for suggesting possible answers - that's what answers are for. The comments that have been removed were largely of the latter type. Comments on Stack Exchange are ephemeral and you should not expect *any* comment to be preserved indefinitely.

For more discussion of this, see [discussions about deleted comments on our meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomments%5D+deleted) and [on mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomments%5D+deleted).